# Concatenating variables to pass to exe in powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm writing a powershell script which calls an exe using the input parameters. This is my code:

```
param([string]$sourceIP, [string]$destinationIP, [string]$prefix)
$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"
try
{
    Write-Host "Starting Copy of Keyspaces to Dev"
    Write-Host "Copying One"
    .\CopyDatabase.exe -s $sourceIP -o $($prefix)_one -d $destinationIP -n $($prefix)_one -c
    Start-Sleep -s 2
    Write-Host "Copying Two"
    .\CopyDatabase.exe -s $sourceIP -o $($prefix)_two -d $destinationIP -n $($prefix)_two -c
    Start-Sleep -s 2
    Write-Host "Copying Three"
    .\CopyDatabase.exe -s $sourceIP -o $($prefix)_three -d $destinationIP -n $($prefix)_three -c
    Start-Sleep -s 2
    Write-Host "Copying Four"
    .\CopyDatabase.exe -s $sourceIP -o $($prefix)_four -d $destinationIP -n $($prefix)_four -c
    Write-Host "Finished Backup"
}
catch
{
    write-host "EXCEPTION:"
    write-host "Exception Type: $($_.Exception.GetType().FullName)"
    write-host "Exception Message: $($_.Exception.Message)"
    exit -1
}
```

It's working as I expect, except that `$($prefix)_keyspace` gives me `prefix _keyspace` where I want `prefix_keyspace`. I'm sure I can write a function or make a new variable for each concatenation, but I'm wondering if there's a command I can use for this that'll save me from having to do that. Thanks!

Comment: `${prefix}_one`

Comment: @PetSerAl Perfect, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the try block with this:

```
try
{
    Write-Host "Starting Copy of Keyspaces to Dev"
    Write-Host "Copying One"
    .\CopyDatabase.exe -s $sourceIP -o ${prefix}_one -d $destinationIP -n ${prefix}_one -c
    Start-Sleep -s 2
    Write-Host "Copying Two"
    .\CopyDatabase.exe -s $sourceIP -o ${prefix}_two -d $destinationIP -n ${prefix}_two -c
    Start-Sleep -s 2
    Write-Host "Copying Three"
    .\CopyDatabase.exe -s $sourceIP -o ${prefix}_three -d $destinationIP -n ${prefix}_three -c
    Start-Sleep -s 2
    Write-Host "Copying Four"
    .\CopyDatabase.exe -s $sourceIP -o ${prefix}_four -d $destinationIP -n ${prefix}_four -c
    Write-Host "Finished Backup"
}
```

This should do your work. Not tested.